# Is MATLAB vector length a constant operation?

Tags: matlab

I assume that MATLAB vectors/matrices have some meta data about dim/size/lengths. So length(a) is supposed to be a very fast operation if a is of vector. Since MATLAB doc does not talk about complexity in general, do we have any way to confirm this?

Comment: Do you mean constant in a complexity way or constant in a sense that it always returns the same value (non dynamic)?

Comment: You are correct.  "Under the hood" MATLAB stores and maintains a size for all array types, and the `length` operator merely retrieves this value.  It isn't quite a simple variable reference, because length has to look at all size dimensions and pick the largest, so it is O(n) in the number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. "Under the hood" MATLAB stores and maintains a size for all array types, and the length operator merely retrieves this value. It isn't quite a simple variable reference, because length has to look at all size dimensions and pick the largest, so it is O(n) in the number of dimensions.